# Resize an image using MS Picture manager is not working

Tags: html, css, image, layout, paint

I have a large picture (2062 x 1447), and i want to resize it to be presented as a logo inside my web site, so i want to resize it to be (202 X 44). so i open the picture using MS Picture manager 2010, and i seelct to resize the image to a custom width and height, then i type 202 & 44 as follow:-

[image]

but the new size will be 63 X 44.. not sure why i can not define it as 202 X 44 ?

Comment: This isn't a programming question?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is because the program tries to keep the aspect ratio so the result is just a smaller version of the original without stretching the image in one direction.  Maybe there is a checkbox not shown in the screenshot to lift this limitation‽